# How to set different “step” on axis X in my figure in matplotlib python 2.7 or 3.5?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
y = [5,6,7,10,100,10000,1000000]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(x), max(x)+1, 1.0))
plt.show()
```

You see, the biggest value is 1000000, if one value is very big, the other small values seems zero from the chart.

Can i use different steps for the axis Y?

The axis Y like this: small step ... middle step ... big step ...

Comment: sorry for the typo, the title should:
How to set different “step” on axis Y in my figure in matplotlib python 2.7 or 3.5?

Comment: Don't use the no-longer supported python 2.7 unless absolutely necessary. You should definitely be using python 3 now.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a logarithmic scale by setting [`plt.yscale()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yscale.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    plt.yscale('log')
    x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
    y = [5,6,7,10,100,10000,1000000]
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.xticks(np.arange(min(x), max(x)+1, 1.0))
    plt.show()
```

[image]